# How to pass a variable in javascript to an HTML string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a variable to the inline JavaScript but its not working.

```
var namealert = key;

     $("#alerta").append("<div class='alert_item clearfix'><a href='#' id='delete_alert' onclick='localStorage.removeItem('" +namealert+ "'');'><img width='15px' style='margin-right:10px;opacity: 0.5;' src='img/error.png'></a><div class='date'>"+obj['0']+"</div><br><div class='title'>"+obj['1']+"</div><br><div class='msg'>"+obj['2']+"</div><br><a href='#' id='candidatar' onclick='candidatar()'><img width='100px' style='margin-right:10px;opacity: 0.8;' src='img/disponivel.png'></a></div>");
```

The output is:

```html
<a href="#" id="delete_alert" onclick="localStorage.removeItem(" alerts_1481117090'');'>...</a>
```

I need it to be `localStorage.removeItem('alerts_1481117090')`;

Comment: Don't do that.  You should add event handlers in JS.

Comment: Look at your quotes. `onclick='localStorage.removeItem('` followed by the rest of the stuff. In this particular case, you can try `onclick='delete localStorage."+namealert+"'` but really you should be using DOM functions and event handlers.

Comment: Or if you must: `\`<div class='alert_item clearfix'>
  <a href='#' id='delete_alert' data-name="${namealert}">
    <img width='15px ' style='margin-right:10px;opacity: 0.5; ' src='img/error.png '>
  </a>
  <div class='date'>${obj[0]}</div>
  <br>
  <div class='title'>${obj[1]}</div>
  <br>
  <div class='msg'>${obj[2]}</div>
  <br>
  <a href='#' id='candidatar' onclick='return candidatar() '>
    <img width='100px' style='margin-right:10px;opacity: 0.8;' src='img/disponivel.png'>
  </a>
</div>\``

Comment: tks that worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of people have downvoted you but nobody's really given a concrete example of what we mean by "adding event handlers", since technically the onclick method you are using *is* an event handler (just not a good way to do what you are trying to do).

```js
var $newElement = $("#alert")
  .append("<div class='alert_item clearfix'>Click me!</div>");
    
// $newElement is a jQuery object returned by .append()

// set a click event handler. this is much better than doing the html
// onClick method you had in your question, because it requires no
// stringified javascript code evaluation.

$newElement.on("click", function (ev) {
 alert("Hey, I was clicked! " + ev.target);
    // your local storage code here instead
});
```

```css
.alert_item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alert">
<!-- elements to append here -->
</div>
```

You're probably just getting into javascript by the looks of it, but don't get discouraged. It's a strange language for sure, but once you get more of a feel for how things work, there's a great book called ["JavaScript, the Good Parts"](http://bdcampbell.net/javascript/book/javascript_the_good_parts.pdf) on how the language can be used safely and powerfully.

Comment: Upvoting you @ahirschberg for not being a standard Stack Overflow down vote [swear word here] . << this is the best I could do without triggering the filter!

Comment: im using it in a complex app on a loop that reads alot of things... thats why i was unable to use a event handlers , i real dont understand the downvotes... the solution posted by  Niet the Dark Absol  worked... but tks for ur help ...